# Manipular e filtrar Notificações no Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notification, android-service

Estou criando uma aplicação para Android na qual utilizo um a `NotificationListenerService` para tentar interceptar as notificações.
A intenção é interceptar todas notificações e deixar que passe somente as que o usuário possui pre-cadastro no aplicativo.

Até então uso o método `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)` para ler a notificação e isso funciona ate certo ponto. Consigo ler a notificação e remove-la da barra de status (*status bar*) , porém o evento de ***push*** de todos aplicativos continua notificando (toca e vibra).

Gostaria de saber  se é possivel gerenciar esse *push notification* de **outros aplicativos** que não sejam o meu.

Exemplo: o usuário configura no meu *app* que só quer receber notificação do GMAIL , se receber uma notificação do WhatsApp ela deve passar no meu `Listener` e não permitir que essa notificação fique no *status bar* e nem seja notificada (*push*)